# Conexión de Php con una base de datos Mysql PhpMyAdmin en la nube

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Cordial saludo equipo, espero se encuentren bien quiero pedirles el favor con lo siguiente referente a conectar
una base de datos Mysql PhpMyAdmin alojada en un Hosting gratuito con una aplicación Php en NetBeans
tengo el siguiente código en Php :

```
<?php
$host = 'http://hecamava.ueuo.com/pma/index.php';
$basededatos = '349049';
$usuariodb = '349049@localhost';
$clavedb = 'MiContraseña';
error_reporting(0);
$conexion = new mysqli($host, $usuariodb, $clavedb, $basededatos,3306);

echo  $conexion->connect_error;
if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
   echo "Fallo al conectar a Mysql: (" .$mysqli->connect_errno .") " .$mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo "Vamos por buen camino pero puede haber error ";
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
?>
```

Pero desafortunadamente me muestra el siguiente error:

Vale mencionar que estoy utilizando el motor WamppServer,

Muchas gracias por la colaboración que me puedan brindar!.

Comment: Ese host es una página web, cámbialo por: `$host = 'hecamava.ueuo.com';`

Comment: En el host debes habilitar las conexiones remotas a MySQL y, seguramente, usar la IP para conectar. Aunque dudo que en servidores gratuitos o compartidos te permitan cambiar la configuración.

Comment: Hola aeportugal muchas gracias, modifique el código por lo que me dijo pero ahora me muestra el siguiente error: Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder. Fallo al conectar a Mysql: ()

Comment: Gracias Triby, voy a averiguar si el servidor FreeWHA, permite realizar lo que me comenta.

Comment: Dudo que el usuario db sea `$usuariodb = '349049@localhost';`... diria que la coletilla `@localhost` sobra. No uses el login de tu panel de control para la conexion de la base de datos, encontraras los datos correctos dentro de tu panel de control por donde este la seccion de la base de datos, y procura averiguar si realmente permiten conexiones externas.